# What FIRApp.deleteApp does and when should I use it?

Tags: firebase

The iOS SDK of Firebase provides the function [`FIRApp.deleteApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRApp#-deleteapp) which, according to the documentation:

> Cleans up the current FIRApp, freeing associated data and returning its name to the pool for future use.

A similar function is available in the JavaScript SDK but not in the Java or C++ ones.

What this function does and when should I use it?

My understanding is that this function works as a destructor and thus I am supposed to call it when my app is closing. Is it correct? Should I call it on `FIRApp.defaultApp` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FIRApp` object contains references to the configuration data of your Firebase project. It is a lightweight object, mostly using a bit of memory keep those settings available when your application needs them.

Most applications create only a single `FIRApp` instance for the entire duration of their lifecycle. In such cases the resources will be automatically released when the application exists, and there is no need to explicitly delete the `FIRApp` instance.